# Im trying to remove a group from a bunch of subfolders permission using powershell, but for some reason it doesn't apply to the subfolder

Tags: powershell

Im trying to remove a group from a bunch of subfolders permission using powershell, but for some reason it doesnt apply to the subfolder, it oly runs and apply the changes to the main folder, here is the code.
Can someone help?

```
$grupo = "PAULWURTH\Domain Users"
$dir = "C:\Robocopy\TESTE\userdata$"

$subfolder=Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Directory -Recurse
foreach ($subfolder in $dir){               
# Disable inherit
$acl = Get-ACL -Path $subfolder
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True)
Set-Acl -Path $subfolder -AclObject $acl
# Removes group permission
$acl = Get-Item $subfolder |get-acl
$acl.Access |where {$_.IdentityReference -eq $grupo} |%{$acl.RemoveAccessRule($_)}
$acl |Set-Acl
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is how you are using the variables `$subfolder` and `$dir` the wrong way in the `foreach` statement.

```
$grupo = "PAULWURTH\Domain Users"
$dir = "C:\Robocopy\TESTE\userdata$"

$allSubFolders=Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Directory -Recurse

foreach ($subfolder in $allSubFolders){               
# Disable inherit
$acl = Get-ACL -Path $subfolder
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True)
Set-Acl -Path $subfolder -AclObject $acl
# Removes group permission
$acl = Get-Item $subfolder |get-acl
$acl.Access |where {$_.IdentityReference -eq $grupo} |%{$acl.RemoveAccessRule($_)}
$acl |Set-Acl
}
```

Comment: Nice catch! I looked over OPs code like 5 times and couldn't see where was the mistake.